# How to install/configure Caffe ? Python anaconda links to GOMP_4.0 and throws error

Tags: gcc, anaconda, caffe, pycaffe

I have lost a day in trying to figure out how to install caffe. Finally I built everything including pycaffe without errors. But when I now run "import caffe" in my little test pythons script, I get the following error

```
ImportError: /usr/progtools/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0)
```

I have found this github issue https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/1225
where at the bottom someone says that its because gcc version within anaconda is 4.* while I've compiled everything with 5.4. I am using CUDA 8.0, so it shouldn't have problems with gcc 4.8.5 (that was cuda 7.5) because 5.* is supported.

Answer (score 5):

It's just caused of Anaconda's gcc libs was compiled by gcc4.xx. by the system owned gcc version is gcc5.xx...

I've hacked this problem with copy

libgomp.so.1.0.0, libquadmath.so.0.0.0, libstdc++.so.6.0.21 these files 
from :

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

to :

/yourAnacondaPath/anaconda2/pkgs/libgcc-4.8.5-2/lib

/yourAnacondaPath/anaconda2/lib

and then create the links;
it works for me